# insert an application between microphone and other applications

Tags: windows, audio, signal-processing, microphone, audio-processing

To the best of my knowledge, this hasn't been asked or addressed before. Here is my question:

I am using Windows 8.1 and want to write an application that will work between the microphone and any other application that uses the microphone like Skype, Hangout .... I can further exemplify the the application in my mind as follows: For a very simple case I would like to add noise to the input of the microphone whether it is being used by Skype or Hangout or any voice recording app. You can think of any signal processing method to be a possible candidate for my application aside noise.

I have to make the microphone input go through my application whatever requests the usage of the microphone. I know this sounds like overwriting the microphone firmware but I would like to do it at the application level. It is almost like I want to redirect all the microphone input through my application and give the output of my application as the microphone source to all other microphone dependent applications.

Do you know of any way to do this or any similar application?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It can certainly be done at the driver level, but I don't know about doing it in userspace. You would create a driver that opens the audio source, does its work, and presents the output as another source. There are loopback drivers out there that let you treat an audio output as a new source for recording the audio played by your system. Your driver would be very similar. Unfortunately you'll have a lot of hoops to jump through with WHQL and signing if you want to mass distribute it.

Comment: Thanks Katie, it seems like I have to go through all the permission process unless someone knows of a way to the other way around, my research indicates a driver level solution as the only possible way as well